# Wave equation - dissipation

Tags: waves

The book states that the wave equation assumes no dispersion and no dissipation, with dissipation defined as a loss of energy and thus a diminution of amplitude.

How can a spherical wave be described by the wave equation if it's amplitude decreases like $\frac{1}{r}$ ? It seems contradictory ...

Comment: I think the book was talking about plane waves in which the amplitude remains constant.

Answer (score 6):

I assume you're talking about the simple wave equation 
$$\ddot \phi=\phi'' \qquad (1) $$
To simplify things, let's talk about one dimensional waves. Everything still holds for higher dimensions, you just replace $\phi'$ by $\vec\nabla\phi$ everywhere. The energy density is
$$u=\frac{1}{2}\left((\dot\phi)^2+(\phi')^2\right)\ .$$

Note that $u$ is the local energy **density**, and it is not at all constant (except for special cases such as standing waves or plane waves). However, the **total** energy of the system, which is given by
$$U=\int u\, d^3\!x$$
is constant. This is easy to see if you multiply $(1)$ by $\dot \phi$ to get
$$
\begin{align}
0&=\dot \phi\left(\ddot\phi-\phi''\right)
=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{1}{2}\dot\phi\right)^2-\dot\phi\phi''\\
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{1}{2}\dot\phi^2\right)-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\phi'\dot\phi\right)+\phi'\dot\phi'
=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left[\frac{1}{2}\dot\phi^2+\frac{1}{2}\phi''^2\right]-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\phi'\dot\phi\right)\\
&=\frac{\partial }{\partial t}u-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\phi'\dot\phi\right)
\end{align}
$$
This is known as (the) [continuity equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation). The quantity $J=\phi'\dot\phi$ is known as the energy flux. To see that the global energy is constant, apply Gauss' theorem to $\dot u$.

The physical meaning of the continuity equation is that energy is **globally** conserved, but locally it is not necessarily so. **Local** changes in the energy density $u$ are compensated by the [divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence) of the energy flux.

Answer (score 1):

The energy in the wave is distributed over larger and larger surface area as the spherical surface expands - unlike an ocean surface wave moving in only one dimension. I suppose in the spherical wave you could say there is a 'dissipation' over the surface. No losses in the wave, but rather distribution of the energy over larger area